# How to combine list from Fn::FindInMap with additional items?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have next CloudFormation file:

```
Mappings:
  MyMap:
    us-east-1:
      Roles:
        - "roleA"
        - "roleB"
    ...

Resources:
  MyPolicy:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
    PolicyDocument:
      Statement:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRole"
          Resource:
            Fn::FindInMap: ["MyMap", !Ref AWS::Region, "Roles"]
```

Everything works fine, however now I need to add an extra role that would be defined for all regions, however simply adding additional role to `Resource:` section doesn't work, since it fails with template syntax error.

Is there a way to combine list of results from `FindInMap` and another item? Something like:

```
Resource:
  Fn::FindInMap: ["MyMap", !Ref AWS::Region, "Roles"]
  - "roleC"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, you can**, but it won't be pretty:

```
Resource: 
  Fn::Split:
    - ','
    - Fn::Join:
      - ','
      - - !Join [',', !FindInMap ["MyMap", !Ref "AWS::Region", "Roles"]]
        - 'roleC'
```

Basically, first you join the `MyMap` list into a string, then you add `roleC` to the string, and then split it into `List of Strings`.

Comment: ah I've seen this solution, hoped there is something prettier, thanks

Comment: @Orest No problem. I'm not aware of anything nicer, but it should work. Have you checked yet?

Comment: @Orest Glad to hear. If so, accepting the answer would be appreciated.